# Python: Cannot import name/IndexError: List index out of range

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, numpy, importerror

I'm still pretty new to Python, and I didn't write most of this code, I'm just trying to get it to work. I have the following two .py files:

This one is called FnSim.py-

```
import numpy,sys, os
import math



def intFn(kVars,params): # Do not change the name of this function

sinTh = kVars['y']/(numpy.sqrt(kVars['y']**2+(1000.)**2))
I = 4*((numpy.sin((numpy.pi*.7*sinTh)/.0006)/((.7*sinTh)/.0006))**2)*numpy.cos((numpy.pi*1.2*sinTh)/.0006)**2
if not math.isnan(I):
    return I
else:
    print 'Hello'
    return 0.0
'''
sinTh = kVars['y']/(numpy.sqrt(kVars['y']**2+(params['R0'])**2))
A1 = numpy.complex(params['A1r'],params['A1i'])*numpy.e**(((-numpy.pi*params['p']*sinTh)/.0006)*1j)
A2 = numpy.complex(params['A2r'],params['A2i'])*numpy.e**(((numpy.pi*params['p']*sinTh)/.0006)*1j)
return (A1+A2)*numpy.conjugate(A1+A2)
'''
def simFn():
"""
    This is the function that will do the actual simulating. Fill out the filepaths below.
"""

nTrueDir="./data/nTrueSF.npy"#Location to save the nTrue File
inputKVDir="./data/flatY.txt"#Loaction of the Generated MC KV text File
outputWeightDir="./data/wnListSF.npy"#Location where the weighted mask file will be saved

iList = numpy.load("./data/iListSF.npy")#Location of the list of intensities. 

iMax = iList.max()
print iMax         
gS.simulate(nTrueDir,inputKVDir,outputWeightDir,iList,iMax)


from generalSim import generalSim
inputKVDir="./data/FlatY.txt"#Loaction of the Generated MC KV File(Same as above)
gS = generalSim(KVDir = inputKVDir)
if sys.argv[1] == "i":
numpy.save("./data/iListSF.npy",gS.calcIList({'A2r': 186.55622562665766, 'R0': 1000.0, 'A1r': 186.5549385015023, 'p': 1.2010987369259563, 'A2i': 0.0, 'A1i': 0.4681942082158097}))
elif sys.argv[1] == "s":
simFn()
```

This one is called generalSim.py-

```
import numpy
import os, sys
import fileinput
from FnSim import intFn
from random import random

class generalSim (object):

def __init__(self,KVDir):
    self.KVDir = KVDir

def calcIList(self,params): 
    n = 0 
    iList = numpy.zeros(shape = (1))
    for line in fileinput.input([self.KVDir]): 
        iList.resize(n+1)       
        kvAs = line.split(",")
        kvAx = {kvA.split('=')[0]:float(kvA.split('=')[1]) for kvA in kvAs}
        iList[n] = intFn(kvAx,params)
        sys.stdout.write(str(n)+"\r")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        n+=1

    return iList

def simulate(self,nTrueDir,inputKVDir,outputWeightDir,iList,iMax):

    nTrueList = [((1.0/(iList.shape[0]))*(iList.sum(0)))]  
    numpy.save(nTrueDir,nTrueList)

    wList=iList[:]/iMax

    wnList=numpy.zeros(shape=(wList.shape[0]))

    for wn in range(len(wList)):            
        if wList[wn]>random():                
            wnList[wn] = 1 

    numpy.save(outputWeightDir,wnList)
```

I also have a text file called FlatY.txt in a folder labeled 'data'. The FlatY.txt contains one million lines of Y values.

I need to run the files so that I can create the .npy files listed in the FnSim.py. I don't know Linux very well, but my intention is to have the files placed in the 'data' folder. However, if I try to compile FnSim.py, the console shows this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "FnSim.py", line 38, in <module>

    from generalSim import generalSim

  File "/home/gendreau/workspace/generalSim.py", line 5, in <module>

    from FnSim import intFn

  File "/home/gendreau/workspace/FnSim.py", line 38, in <module>

    from generalSim import generalSim

ImportError: cannot import name generalSim
```

When I try to run generalSim.py, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "generalSim.py", line 5, in <module>

    from FnSim import intFn

  File "/home/gendreau/workspace/FnSim.py", line 41, in <module>

    if sys.argv[1] == "i":

IndexError: list index out of range
```

What can fix to resolve these problems and generate the necessary files?

Comment: You have a circular import; `generalSim` imports `FnSim` which imports `generalSim`. Try not to do that. The `generalSim` module only has executed up to line 5, anything after that doesn't exist yet and cannot be imported.

Comment: Also, please use the `{}` button on the toolbar to format code after pasting it in. Don't try and 'fix' the formatting by indenting individual lines; indentation is too important in Python code for you to leave the post like this, as it won't run at all with the incorrect indentation you left it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a kind of workaround but see below, I hope it helps in your work:

Because you have a lot of circular import i.e. first module calls the second module, which calls the first and so on, the most straightforward solution to get the needed result is to merge the two files avoiding the circular imports:

```
import numpy
import os, sys
import math
import fileinput
from random import random



class generalSim (object):

    def __init__(self,KVDir):
        self.KVDir = KVDir

    def calcIList(self,params): 
        n = 0 
        iList = numpy.zeros(shape = (1))
        for line in fileinput.input([self.KVDir]): 
            iList.resize(n+1)       
            kvAs = line.split(",")
            kvAx = {kvA.split('=')[0]:float(kvA.split('=')[1]) for kvA in kvAs}
            iList[n] = intFn(kvAx,params)
            sys.stdout.write(str(n)+"\r")
            sys.stdout.flush()
            n+=1

        return iList

    def simulate(self,nTrueDir,inputKVDir,outputWeightDir,iList,iMax):

        nTrueList = [((1.0/(iList.shape[0]))*(iList.sum(0)))]  
        numpy.save(nTrueDir,nTrueList)

        wList=iList[:]/iMax

        wnList=numpy.zeros(shape=(wList.shape[0]))

        for wn in range(len(wList)):            
            if wList[wn]>random():                
                wnList[wn] = 1 

        numpy.save(outputWeightDir,wnList)


def intFn(kVars,params): # Do not change the name of this function
    sinTh = kVars['y']/(numpy.sqrt(kVars['y']**2+(1000.)**2))
    I = 4*((numpy.sin((numpy.pi*.7*sinTh)/.0006)/((.7*sinTh)/.0006))**2)*numpy.cos((numpy.pi*1.2*sinTh)/.0006)**2

    if not math.isnan(I):
        return I
    else:
        print 'Hello'
        return 0.0

'''
sinTh = kVars['y']/(numpy.sqrt(kVars['y']**2+(params['R0'])**2))
A1 = numpy.complex(params['A1r'],params['A1i'])*numpy.e**(((-numpy.pi*params['p']*sinTh)/.0006)*1j)
A2 = numpy.complex(params['A2r'],params['A2i'])*numpy.e**(((numpy.pi*params['p']*sinTh)/.0006)*1j)
return (A1+A2)*numpy.conjugate(A1+A2)
'''

def simFn():
    """
        This is the function that will do the actual simulating. Fill out the filepaths below.
    """
    nTrueDir="./data/nTrueSF.npy"#Location to save the nTrue File
    inputKVDir="./data/flatY.txt"#Loaction of the Generated MC KV text File
    outputWeightDir="./data/wnListSF.npy"#Location where the weighted mask file will be saved

    iList = numpy.load("./data/iListSF.npy")#Location of the list of intensities. 

    iMax = iList.max()
    print iMax         
    gS.simulate(nTrueDir,inputKVDir,outputWeightDir,iList,iMax)


inputKVDir="./data/FlatY.txt"#Loaction of the Generated MC KV File(Same as above)

gS = generalSim(KVDir = inputKVDir)

if sys.argv[1] == "i":
    numpy.save("./data/iListSF.npy",gS.calcIList({'A2r': 186.55622562665766, 'R0': 1000.0, 'A1r': 186.5549385015023, 'p': 1.2010987369259563, 'A2i': 0.0, 'A1i': 0.4681942082158097}))

elif sys.argv[1] == "s":
    simFn()
```

Furthermore you have to run this file with passing argument `i` or `s` to it at the command line or directly erasing the ignorable row from the script at this:

```
if sys.argv[1] == "i":
    numpy.save("./data/iListSF.npy",gS.calcIList({'A2r': 186.55622562665766, 'R0': 1000.0, 'A1r': 186.5549385015023, 'p': 1.2010987369259563, 'A2i': 0.0, 'A1i': 0.4681942082158097}))

elif sys.argv[1] == "s":
    simFn()
```

Or you can change your code as follows adding an extra variable as `runmode` and you can set the actual running mode via this.

```
import numpy
import os, sys
import math
import fileinput
from random import random

######
run_mode = "s" # or you can change it to "i"
######

class generalSim (object):

    def __init__(self,KVDir):
        self.KVDir = KVDir

    def calcIList(self,params): 
        n = 0 
        iList = numpy.zeros(shape = (1))
        for line in fileinput.input([self.KVDir]): 
            iList.resize(n+1)       
            kvAs = line.split(",")
            kvAx = {kvA.split('=')[0]:float(kvA.split('=')[1]) for kvA in kvAs}
            iList[n] = intFn(kvAx,params)
            sys.stdout.write(str(n)+"\r")
            sys.stdout.flush()
            n+=1

        return iList

    def simulate(self,nTrueDir,inputKVDir,outputWeightDir,iList,iMax):

        nTrueList = [((1.0/(iList.shape[0]))*(iList.sum(0)))]  
        numpy.save(nTrueDir,nTrueList)

        wList=iList[:]/iMax

        wnList=numpy.zeros(shape=(wList.shape[0]))

        for wn in range(len(wList)):            
            if wList[wn]>random():                
                wnList[wn] = 1 

        numpy.save(outputWeightDir,wnList)


def intFn(kVars,params): # Do not change the name of this function
    sinTh = kVars['y']/(numpy.sqrt(kVars['y']**2+(1000.)**2))
    I = 4*((numpy.sin((numpy.pi*.7*sinTh)/.0006)/((.7*sinTh)/.0006))**2)*numpy.cos((numpy.pi*1.2*sinTh)/.0006)**2

    if not math.isnan(I):
        return I
    else:
        print 'Hello'
        return 0.0

'''
sinTh = kVars['y']/(numpy.sqrt(kVars['y']**2+(params['R0'])**2))
A1 = numpy.complex(params['A1r'],params['A1i'])*numpy.e**(((-numpy.pi*params['p']*sinTh)/.0006)*1j)
A2 = numpy.complex(params['A2r'],params['A2i'])*numpy.e**(((numpy.pi*params['p']*sinTh)/.0006)*1j)
return (A1+A2)*numpy.conjugate(A1+A2)
'''

def simFn():
    """
        This is the function that will do the actual simulating. Fill out the filepaths below.
    """
    nTrueDir="./data/nTrueSF.npy"#Location to save the nTrue File
    inputKVDir="./data/flatY.txt"#Loaction of the Generated MC KV text File
    outputWeightDir="./data/wnListSF.npy"#Location where the weighted mask file will be saved

    iList = numpy.load("./data/iListSF.npy")#Location of the list of intensities. 

    iMax = iList.max()
    print iMax         
    gS.simulate(nTrueDir,inputKVDir,outputWeightDir,iList,iMax)


inputKVDir="./data/FlatY.txt"#Loaction of the Generated MC KV File(Same as above)

gS = generalSim(KVDir = inputKVDir)

####
if run_mode == "i":
    numpy.save("./data/iListSF.npy",gS.calcIList({'A2r': 186.55622562665766, 'R0': 1000.0, 'A1r': 186.5549385015023, 'p': 1.2010987369259563, 'A2i': 0.0, 'A1i': 0.4681942082158097}))

elif run_mode == "s":
    simFn()
####
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. With this, it still gives 'IndexError: list index out of range'.

Comment: Because as I wrote you have to pass an argument at the command line "i" or "s".